# sass shows everything in one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, sass

[Doc](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note) of rails-sass says that one should not use `require_tree` but use things like `@import "mixins/**/*`

import puts everything in one file. For ex my application.css looks like:

```
@import 'markdown';
@import 'issues';
@import 'button';
@import 'comment';
@import 'feed';
@import 'form';
@import 'guide';
@import 'hero';
@import 'map';
@import 'message';
@import 'nav';
@import 'project';
@import 'toolbar';
@import 'user';
@import 'widget';
```

this generates a 1000 lines application.css file and it gets really difficult to see in debugger where is a particular style is coming from. Everything says it is coming from application.css.

Is there a way I can get back that one feature of `require tree .`?

Comment: Most people *want* this behavior because it reduces HTTP requests, which is better for the user.  If you want to debug, you're supposed to use Source Maps (see: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/).

Comment: Thanks cimmanon! This looks like correct solution. I am still try to set this up with my project. Also found https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps would you like to answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the desired behavior for production but in development you probably want to add

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

to development.rb. This will cause the file to be compiled separately.